# Does Azure Web Apps require a WAF

Tags: azure-web-app-service

we are working on some web apps in the cloud and were wondering if we really need a WAF. These web apps are very small and they require at most 2 instances. Our IT department asked us if we can protect our apps with a WAF.

We know that we could do this with ASE but it is really expensive and we do not see the need of putting our small apps within an ASE.

So my question is: Does Azure provide any king of protection by default for the App Services. In the documentation there is nothing about how protected App Service is, it only says how to protect it using SSL and Authentication but there is nothing about protecting apps against certain attacks.

Are there any best practices to this topic?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As [Azure Web App sandbox](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Azure-Web-App-sandbox) noted as follows:

> All Azure Web Apps (as well as Mobile App/Services, WebJobs and Functions) run in a secure environment called a sandbox. Each app runs inside its own sandbox, isolating its execution from other instances on the same machine as well as providing an additional degree of security and privacy which would otherwise not be available. The sandbox mechanism aims to ensure that each app running on a machine will have a minimum guaranteed level of service; furthermore, the runtime limits enforced by the sandbox protects apps from being adversely affected by other resource-intensive apps which may be running on the same machine.

For Infrastructure and platform security, Azure would isolate your App Service apps and communication of sensitive datas (e.g. sql connectionstring, appId, appSecret,etc.) are always encrypted. Also, App service would provide threat management protects App Service resources from malware, DDoS, MITM, and other threats.

For Application security, you need to develop, manage your application in a security way. The frequent threats would be SQL Injection, Session hijacking, Cross-site-scripting, etc.

Additionally, you could leverage [integration with Tinfoil Security](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/web-vulnerability-scanning-for-azure-app-service-powered-by-tinfoil-security/) to perform penetration testing on your app and follow the instructions to fix possible vulnerability.